# How to scroll to specific location on button click in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-scroll

I'm making a website using `react` and I want a `button` to scroll to footer section of my website. I am using `react-scroll` and it is working. I am also using `material ui` to style my `button` using their `Button component`. This is my code snippet.

```
<StyledButton>
    <Link
     activeClass="active"
     to="Contact"
     spy={true}
     smooth={true}
     offset={-20}
     duration={900}
    >
     Get In Touch
    </Link>
</StyledButton>
```

This works but the only issue is it only works when I click on the text in the `button`. If I click anywhere else in the `button`(inside the button but not on text), it doesn't scroll to footer section. Any suggestions on how do I do that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You should place your `Link` outside of the `button`.

```
<Link 
    activeClass="active"
    to="Contact"
    spy={true}
    smooth={true}
    offset={-20}
    duration={900}
    >
    <StyledButton>
        Get In Touch
    </StyledButton>
 </Link>
```

This way, your whole button gets 'linked' to the element you provided

Comment: I also thought about it but it gives me an error saying: parsing error: unexpected token

Comment: That's your whole error? If not, could you post your log when the error occurs?

Comment: yes, that's the whole error I get. It fails to parse the styledbutton component inside link.

Comment: It's not something like `parsing error: unexpected token 'some_character'. expected: 'something'` ?

Comment: Did you import `Link` as: `Link = Scroll.Link`? I did the same thing and for me it works. Please make sure to paste the whole error

Comment: I am importing link as import {Link} from 'react-scroll'. Do you want me to import it as import Link as Scroll.Link? from 'react-scroll'?  And about the error, I do not get anything like 'some_character expected' after unexpected token.

Comment: You should import `Link` as `Link = Scroll.Link` and, before, `import Scroll from 'react-scroll'`. I have always used it like that and had no problems